# Truncate C++ string fields generated by ostringstream, iomanip:setw

Tags: c++, truncate, ostringstream, setw

In C++ I need string representations of integers with leading zeroes, where the representation has 8 digits and no more than 8 digits, truncating digits on the right side if necessary.  I thought I could do this using just ostringstream and iomanip.setw(), like this:

```
int num_1 = 3000;
ostringstream out_target;

out_target << setw(8) << setfill('0') << num_1;
cout << "field: " << out_target.str() << " vs input: " << num_1 << endl;
```

The output here is:

```
field: 00003000 vs input: 3000
```

Very nice! However if I try a bigger number, setw lets the output grow beyond 8 characters:

```
int num_2 = 2000000000;
ostringstream out_target;

out_target << setw(8) << setfill('0') << num_2;
cout << "field: " << out_target.str() << " vs input: " << num_2 << endl;
out_target.str("");
```

output:

```
field: 2000000000 vs input: 2000000000
```

The desired output is "20000000".  There's nothing stopping me from using a second operation to take only the first 8 characters, but is field truncation truly missing from iomanip?  Would the Boost formatting do what I need in one step?

Comment: Shifting magnitude is not truncation - you will need either a string operation, or maths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any way to truncate a numeric field like that. Perhaps it has not been implemented because it would change the value.

`ostream::write()` allows you to truncate a *string* buffer simply enough, as in this example...

```
    int num_2 = 2000000000;
    ostringstream out_target;

    out_target << setw(8) << setfill('0') << num_2;
    cout << "field: ";
    cout.write(out_target.str().c_str(), 8);
    cout << " vs input: " << num_2 << endl;
```

Comment: it looks like this is about the closest one can get with the standard library.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that snprintf() will write as many chars at it can (I don't think this is guaranteed),

```
char buf[9];
snprintf(buf, 10, "%08d", num);
buf[8] = 0;
cout << std::string(buf) << endl;
```

I am not sure why you want 2 billion to be the same as 20 million. It may make more sense to signal an error on truncation, like this:

```
if (snprintf(buf, 10, "%08d", num) > 8) {
    throw std::exception("oops")
}
```